# cant call IB package

Tags: python

installed ib using distutils and shows up but I am having a hard time calling.  A previous version worked before the updgrade.

```
!pip freeze

...
h5py==2.3.1
ib==0.8.0
ipython==2.2.0
itsdangerous==0.24
....

from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-88684359196c> in <module>()
----> 1 from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
      2 from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
      3 import os.path, time

ImportError: No module named ib.ext.Contract
```

it looks like dist utils is installing the 'ib-0.8.0-py2.7.egg' directory in the 'site packages' directory but no 'ib' directory. any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from ib.ext import Contract` instead of `from ib.ext.Contract import Contract`?

Comment: @mastazi no, the package is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm `pip install ib` is broken (but don't know how -- except that for me it only makes the .egg-info directory, **not** the .egg itself!).  To get `ib` anyway, I'd suggest working from the sources:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/blampe/IbPy.git
$ cd IbPy
$ python setup.py install
$ cd
$ python
>>> from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
>>>
```

...works just fine in this less-automated way!

Comment: I concluded the same :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is already old, but:

- `pip install ib` doesn't install something that was created by `IbPy` maintainers.

The original (originally hosted at `code.google.com` which was the work of *Troy Melhase*) can be installed with:

- `pip install IbPy`

The current (as can be seen in the current repository at https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/) which contains improvements and bugfixes can be installed with:

- `pip install IbPy2`

Installing from the latest sources can also be done directly with `pip` with

- `pip install git+https://github.com/blampe/IbPy.git`

or for systems with no `git` (Windows for example):

- `pip install https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/archive/master.zip`